# Access hadoop on browser in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

My reference for Hadoop installation in Pseudo Distributed Mode is [hadoop_environment_setup](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm). I am using Hadoop 2.7.0 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. 
I am able to verify all applications for a cluster via http://localhost:8088/cluster/nodes as shown in below screenhost.

[image]

My hosts file i.e. /etc/hosts contains the following mapping:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   subash-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC
```

Now, when I try to access Hadoop on browser via http://localhost:50070/, I get webpage not available message.

Now while running

```
start-dfs.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
    Starting namenodes on []
```

Then I enter the hadoop password as follows:

```
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-subash-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC.out
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-subash-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
hadoop@0.0.0.0's password:
```

After password entries, it throws below error:

```
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-subash-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC.out
0.0.0.0: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0:  hdfs://localhost:9000 
0.0.0.0:    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getDefaultUri(FileSystem.java:178)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:460)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress(NameNode.java:454)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:229)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
0.0.0.0: Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0:  hdfs://localhost:9000 
0.0.0.0:    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
16/01/03 15:43:22 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: Are you sure Hadoop services are running? Execute `jps` and check if NameNode is running.

Comment: @MobinRanjbar it's running, when I execute `jps` I get the following output:
`17008 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar  10672 TaskManager  8885 JobManager  
18376 Jps`

Comment: There is no NameNode in the output. Start `start-hdfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` from `/hadoop/sbin` folder. If you have executed them, check the logs in `logs` folder.

Comment: @MobinRanjbar I updated the question with my logs, could you please take  a look.

Comment: The problem is related to your configuration. It seems your `fs.default.name` has some empty spaces(" hdfs://localhost:9000 "). Remove them and restart the services.

Comment: @MobinRanjbar yup it worked, thank you very much :)